# Bitbucket obtain information about all commits of a repository

Tags: repository, feed, commit, bitbucket

I want information about all commits done on my BitBucket repository.

I dont need an XML Feed. I want just a list of commits and the order in which they are committed and possibly information about merging.

On bitbucket websites information is shown in paginated form and is not sufficient for me. It would be nice if could obtain a pdf or something listing all my commits.

Is there a way to do so ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pankaj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a **local clone** and then access the local repository using whatever tools you have that can generate such a PDF. That way you'll have full access to the information you need about commits and merges. Since Mercurial is a distributed version control system, this is really the way you're supposed to access it: locally, not via screen-scraping on Bitbucket.

If you're using Java or Python, then you can use [JavaHg](http://javahg.aragost.com/) or [python-hglib](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PythonHglib) to access the repository. See the [full list of libraries](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer#Libraries).

Comment: @Panx: no problem. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept this answer if it's helpful to you.